# Handling elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, logging

So I have an array dubbed `match` where `match[0]` =

```
[2014-05-30 15:21:20,781] DEBUG [scheduler-4] (DiamondSchedulerRunner.java:41) Current node is not a manager of:publishEmail in tenant:0 
[2014-05-30 15:21:20,781] DEBUG [scheduler-1] (DiamondSchedulerRunner.java:41) Current node is not a manager of:readEmail in tenant:0 
[2014-06-11 10:18:51,370] ERROR [executorWithPoolSizeRange-5] (PushNotificationsServiceBean.java:140) cannot send notification: service Whaler is not available for user himanshu.taunk@hp.com on device Desktop.device.uuid813374 
[2014-05-30 15:21:50,608] DEBUG [scheduler-3] (DiamondSchedulerProxy.java:96) Diamond Scheduler name:index Mode:TENANT_NODE runOnTenant:true split:true 
[2014-05-30 15:21:50,624] DEBUG [scheduler-3] (DiamondSchedulerRunner.java:41) Current node is not a manager of:index in tenant:0 
[2014-06-11 10:18:49,124] ERROR [executorWithPoolSizeRange-5] (PushNotificationsServiceBean.java:140) cannot send notification: service Whaler is not available for user himanshu.taunk@hp.com on device Desktop.device.uuid798084 
[2014-05-30 15:21:50,780] DEBUG [scheduler-5] (DiamondSchedulerProxy.java:96) Diamond Scheduler name:snooze Mode:TENANT_NODE runOnTenant:true split:true 
[2014-05-30 15:21:50,780] DEBUG [scheduler-5] (DiamondSchedulerRunner.java:41) Current node is not a manager of:snooze in tenant:0 
[2014-05-30 15:21:50,796] ERROR [scheduler-4] (DiamondSchedulerProxy.java:96) Diamond Scheduler name:publishEmail Mode:TENANT_NODE runOnTenant:true split:true
```

`match[1]` is the timestamp, `match[2]` is the status, `match[3]` is the thread name, and so on. Is there anyway I could reverse the elements in the first index, `match[0]` such that the first line becomes the last line, and vice versa without messing around with the other indices?

Better yet, could I read through the first index line by line into another array and then just reverse the latter array?

Answer (score 0):

Could you split match[0] with delimiter \n then do a reverse and join?
i.e.

```
match[0] = match[0].split('\n').reverse().join('\n')
```